# vector rowdata to 3 different rowdata java

Tags: java, arrays, vector, filter, 2d

I have one 2 dimension String Vector called rowData

[[Windows, test, test, test, test, test], [Internet, net, net, net, net, net], [Other, other, other, other, other, other], [Windows, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2], [Internet, net2, net2, net2, net2, net2], [Other, other2, other2, other2, other2, other2]]

I read it from file.

I have this 3 categories in my jtable, and i would like to create a filter.

I would like to create  3 piece of 2 d vector like this if the first string value is "Windows", or "Internet", or "Other.

Vector 1:
[[Windows, test, test, test, test, test][Windows, test2, test2, test2, test2, test2]]

Vector 2: [[Internet, net, net, net, net, net],[Internet, net2, net2, net2, net2, net2]]

Vector 3: [[Other, other, other, other, other, other], [Other, other2, other2, other2, other2, other2]]

How can i do that? Any help would be much appreciated!

MY code how i read the file to rowData:

```
try {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./list.dat")); 
    Vector rowData = (Vector) in.readObject();      
    Iterator itr = rowData.iterator();             
    while (itr.hasNext()) {                         
        model.addRow((Vector) itr.next());         
    }
    in.close();    
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

Comment: I solved it. without Vector.  final TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
                   table.setRowSorter(sorter);
                    sorter.setRowFilter(
                     RowFilter.regexFilter("Windows"));

Comment: As a side note: you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it as soon as you have >= 15 reputation.